# How to enter equal keys in mongodb query via php?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

In mongodb bash I can do this:

```
db.collection.find({'field1': /^value1/, 'field2': /^value2/, 'field2': /^value3/});
```

It is very convenient when `field2` is an array. The alternative is:

```
db.collection.find({'$and': [
    {'field1': /^value1/}, 
    {'field2': /^value2/}, 
    {'field2': /^value3/}
]});
```

... which is inconvenient.

But I can't use the first query in php because php array keys must be unique. Is there any way to do this query in php?

Comment: I am surprised the first works in MongoDB JavaScript shell, it shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)** operator which is equivalent to an [**`$and`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operation of the specified values; i.e. the following statement:

```
{ "field2": { "$all": [ /^value2/, /^value3/ ] } }
```

is equivalent to:

```
{ "$and:" [ { "field2": /^value2/ }, { "field2": /^value3/ } ] }
```

Thus your final query would be

```
db.collection.find({
    "field1": /^value1/, 
    "field2": { "$all": [ /^value2/, /^value3/ ] }
});
```

Comment: TBH it is subjective is that is better than an `$and` since it is up to the perspective of someone writing